# Javascript event on tab or window open

Tags: javascript, tabs, window

I'm developing an online production management software and I need to keep track of which pages of the app the user has open.

I'm currently using body onload and onunload -events to modify a page specific key/value -pair in local storage to "true" or "false" which I then use to tell if the user has the page open or not.

The problem is that when I do it like this and the user has multiple instances of the same page open and he closes one of them, then the value of the key in the local storage changes to "false" even when there are still other instances open.

I guess I could try to do this with a kind of a counter which is incremented on the pages body onload event and then decremented on the body onunload event.
But then there is the problem that the body onload event fires also when refreshing the page so then the user could have none of the pages open and the app would still think that there are pages open.

What would be a good way to track wich pages of the site or app the user has open?.

Comment: I guess your counter technique should solve the problem, because on refresh of a page, what fires first is the "onunload" event and then the "onload" event. So when a user refreshes a page, ideally the counter value will decrement first and then increment, and hence it will remain at the same value.

Comment: You're looking for the Page Visibility API  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active